# Hiding an element with multiple toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that lists a lot of data (each row is an offer, and there can be a couple hundred of them). Each offer has data associated with it: a group ID (multiple offers can be in the same group), a cost, if you must trade other items as a requirement to fulfill offer, etc.

I've made a fiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/gd5Nd/

and since i need to include code with fiddle links:

```
    <label class='checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='toggle' id='filterToggle' value='true' data-toggle='filtering' />Filtering Options</label>
<fieldset id='filtering'>
    <label class='checkbox'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='filter' value='1' data-type='req' />Offers with Required Items</label>
    <label class='checkbox'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='toggle' id='groupToggle' value='true' data-toggle='groups' />Filter By Group</label>
    <fieldset id='groups'>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='filter' value='11' data-type='group' />Cap Boosters</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='filter' value='475' data-type='group' />Datacores</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class='checkbox'>
                <input type='checkbox' class='filter' value='24' data-type='group' />Gunslinger Implants</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-condensed' id='offerList'>
    <tr>
        <th>Offer</th>
        <th>Items Req</th>
        <th>LP Cost</th>
        <th>ISK Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1607' data-group='11' data-isk='60000' data-lp='60' data-req='1'>
        <td><a href='offer/1607/'>20x Navy Cap Booster 25</a>

        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>60,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1608' data-group='11' data-isk='125000' data-lp='125' data-req='1'>
        <td><a href='offer/1608/'>20x Navy Cap Booster 50</a>

        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>125</td>
        <td>125,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1609' data-group='11' data-isk='185000' data-lp='185' data-req='1'>
        <td><a href='offer/1609/'>20x Navy Cap Booster 75</a>

        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>185</td>
        <td>185,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1431' data-group='475' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/1431/'>5x Datacore - Amarrian Starship Engineering</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1432' data-group='475' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/1432/'>5x Datacore - High Energy Physics</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1433' data-group='475' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/1433/'>5x Datacore - Laser Physics</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1434' data-group='475' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/1434/'>5x Datacore - Mechanical Engineering</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1435' data-group='475' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/1435/'>5x Datacore - Nanite Engineering</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-1464' data-group='11' data-isk='250000' data-lp='250' data-req='1'>
        <td><a href='offer/1464/'>20x Navy Cap Booster 100</a>

        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>250,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-249' data-group='24' data-isk='375000' data-lp='375' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/249/'>1x Eifyr and Co. 'Gunslinger' Large Projectile Turret
      LP-1001</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>375,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-252' data-group='24' data-isk='375000' data-lp='375' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/252/'>1x Eifyr and Co. 'Gunslinger' Medium Projectile Turret
      MP-801</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>375,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-255' data-group='24' data-isk='375000' data-lp='375' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/255/'>1x Eifyr and Co. 'Gunslinger' Motion Prediction
      MR-701</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>375,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-258' data-group='24' data-isk='375000' data-lp='375' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/258/'>1x Eifyr and Co. 'Gunslinger' Small Projectile Turret
      SP-601</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>375,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='offer-261' data-group='24' data-isk='375000' data-lp='375' data-req='0'>
        <td><a href='offer/261/'>1x Eifyr and Co. 'Gunslinger' Surgical Strike
      SS-901</a>

        </td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>375</td>
        <td>375,000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // !- Bind checkboxes to show filters
    $('input[type="checkbox"].toggle').bind("change", function () {
        if (typeof $(this).data('toggle') != 'undefined') {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $("#" + $(this).data('toggle')).show();
            } else {
                $("#" + $(this).data('toggle')).hide();
            }
        }
    }).trigger('change');

    $('input[type="checkbox"].filter').bind("change", function () {
        switch ($(this).data('type')) {
            case 'group':
                var filtered = $('*[data-group="' + this.value + '"]');
                console.log("Affected offers for " + this.value + ": " + filtered.length);

                filtered.toggleClass('danger');
                break;
            case 'req':
                var filtered = $('*[data-req="1"]');
                filtered.toggleClass('danger');
                break;
        }
    }).trigger('toggle');
});
```

The problem I'm having is that multiple filters may point to the same data row. For example: I have an offer that is part of group 11 (Cap Boosters), and it also requires items to trade. I have two filters that affect this: Has required items filter, and the group filter.

If I were to activate the group filter for group 11, I highlight the group 11 offers. However, when I activate the filter for offers with required items, I want it to remain highlighted. Instead, it removes the highlight.

This is because I'm toggling the class for the highlight on/off. I've tried show()/hide() which pretty much do the same thing (of course). One thing I tried that didn't work was addClass() and removeClass(). I thought it would append the class, so that if you had two filters that added the class, and then removed one filter, the other filter's class would still be active, but it seems that addClass only adds the class if it's not already present.

I could do some checking, such as if I choose to deactivate the group toggle, it will check to see if the req items toggle is still checked. However, that seems like a hack, and I'm not sure if it will work well (the example I have is a simplified version; in reality, there are about 10 groups and I would like to add more filters, so I'm not sure how feasible it would be to recursively check all filters and if they affect the data row every time one filter is checked/unchecked).

I was curious as to how best solve this problem of multiple filters pointing to the same data row.

### Solution

I basically set up, as part of routine JS init, a 'filter container' object initially structured as so: `rowID : Array()`. Every time I add a filter, the filter will add itself to array for that row (so, having two filters in this example, each row could be filtered with `group` or `req`). Every time a filter is applied, we loop through the matching rows, and add/remove the filter from the list. If we're adding a filter, we go ahead and `.hide()` the element as well. If we remove the filter, we check to see if the array is empty, which means no filters are applied and we then `.show()` the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweet. A fellow EVE pilot.

I think your primary problem here is relying too much on simple notions like CSS classes or something to accomplish your goal. It sounds like what you need to do is keep track of all the different market items in a data structure, then go through and "turn on highlight" for the items you want. If it's already highlighted, who cares, otherwise turn it on (and vice versa). This is a strategy I typically use when I have complex hierarchies of collapsible items, or complex groupings such as what you're dealing with.

Comment: o7 This makes so much more sense. Will revise the OP with my solution, which seems to work well

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you describe as a "hack" is fine - and is the only way I can think to do it simply. I had an idea involving adding an additional data-attribute for every filter option and then applying the styling via those instead of the class
IE:

```
<style>
.danger,
[data-req_style=1],
[data-group_style=11],
[data-group_style=475]{
    ...
}
</style>
```

Then rather than toggling the class you could safely add remove multiple filters without interfering with others. BUT that becomes really unmaintainable if you have an arbitrary or ever expanding list of filters.

Your "hack" solution is how I would implement it were it my project. Class selectors and determining the status of check boxes are comparably pretty fast so I wouldn't worry too much about performance even with really large data sets.